# Read differnet audio file formats from folder using Python

Tags: python, audio, format

I am attempting to read different audio file formats from a folder using Python.  The folder contains mainly .wav and .mp3 audio file formats.  When I use the code listed below, I get the error:

> `Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "G:/FAU/PythonCode/scipy_audio_spectrogram.py", line 7, in <module>
>       fs, Audiodata = wavfile.read(AudioName)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py", line 267, in read
>       file_size, is_big_endian = _read_riff_chunk(fid)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py", line 168, in
>   _read_riff_chunk
>       "understood.".format(repr(str1))) ValueError: File format b'ID3\x03'... not understood.`

How to modify the code so that both .wav and .mp3 files can be read from the folder?  Thanks!
Here is the code that I am using:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile # scipy library to read wav files
import numpy as np

AudioName = r'G:\FAU\PythonCode\4201.mp3' # Audio File
fs, Audiodata = wavfile.read(AudioName)
```

Comment: Does it throw the error on .wav files, or just on .mp3 files? Since it's a library to read .wav files, it may not work for .mp3.

Comment: It throws the error just for the .mp3 files.